# inappropriate blocking method call if calling a method marked with @Throws(IOException::class)

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-coroutines

```
suspend fun load(): List<Device> {
    ...
    val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        request.auth(authorizer).get(uri)
    }

    return response.data.devices
}
```

In the above code the call to `auth` works because it is not marked with `@Throws`
but `get` looks like this:

```
@Throws(RequestFailedException::class, IOException::class, SigningException::class)
operator fun get(uri: URI): RestResponse
```

IntelliJ marks the `get`-Function with `Inappropriate blocking method call`

I'm not sure if this is a false/positive or not. If not - how should I handle this situation?
(I can't rewrite the `get`-Function...)

I found this issue report https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39684 and tried to upgrade to coroutines 1.4.0 and to downgrade to 1.8.3 - nothing helped

Comment: I would guess it is related to kotlin plugin and not IDEA itself

Comment: What is version of your kotlin plugin? I'm not sure it will help.